# read specific words in a sas string

Tags: sas

Given a column below, I was trying to separate contact, address,zip, phone, fax & website address using sas 9.1

column 1 : Company_address

> Contact:Sean Collins  Address:6301 NW 5th Way   Suite1700   Fort
>   Lauderdale, FL 33309  Phone:(954) 689-3984  Fax:(954) 689-3985 
>   http://www.aajtech.com

output should be something like this

```
column 2 : Contact - Sean Collins
column 3 : address - 6301 NW 5th Way   Suite1700   Fort Lauderdale, FL
column 4 : zip - 33309 
column 5 : phone - (954) 689-3984
column 6 : fax - (954) 689-3985
column 7 : website - http://www.aajtech.com
```

This is what I was trying.

```
proc sort data=Ex2 out=Ex3 nodup dupout=b_out; 
 by city;
run;

data Final;
set Ex2;
a=find(Company_Address,"http");
website=substr(Company_Address,a,50);
b=find(Company_Address,"Phone:");
phone=substr(Company_Address,b,21);
c=find(Company_Address,"Fax");
Fax=substr(Company_Address,c,19);
Add=substr(Company_Address,1,b-1);
Z=find(Add,"http");
Address=substr(Add,1,z-1);
if Address=website then Address=" ";
drop a b c z Add;
run;
```

some help to figure this out is greatly appreciated.

Note : The question posted here is not part of my job/work, Im a newbie trying to figure out things(these r my own scenarios), reason being curiosity.. The syntax worked out to some extent, however the program is not able to differentiate between company name and contact name thanks.

Comment: Update your question with what you have tried so far...

Comment: have been trying the index, substr functions, scan etc, nothing workd as of now.

Comment: As CarolinaJay notes - update your question with the code you've tried.  SO is not intended to do your work for you, it's to help you do your work better; so show your work so we can do that.

Comment: If your input data doesn't have delimiters or is not on fixed intervals, I don't think it can be parsed. It doesn't matter if this is for work, hobby or home work, we are happy to answer your questions, just make it easy to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably too "localized" for StackOverflow, but I found it interesting and will show a solution anyway.  The coding techniques might be useful to others as well.

```
data Final;
   set Ex2;
   /* Define the variables you want to keep */
   length Contact $30
          Address $60
          Zip     $5
          Phone   $20
          Fax     $20
          Website $60;
   keep Contact Address Zip Phone Fax Website;

   length tmp_addr var value $200;
   tmp_addr = company_address;
   do while(not last_var);
      var = scan(tmp_addr,1,':');
      substr(tmp_addr,1,length(var)+1) = '';
      if index(tmp_addr,':') > 0 then do;
         value = scan(tmp_addr,1,':');
         value = substr(value,1,length(value) - length(scan(value,-1,' '))-1);
         substr(tmp_addr,1,length(value)+1) = '';
         end;
      else do;
         value = tmp_addr;
         last_var = 1;
         end;
      var = left(var);
      value = left(value);
      select(var);
         when ('Contact') do;
            Contact = value;
            end;
         when ('Address') do;
            Zip = scan(value,-1,' ');
            if zipstate(zip) = ' ' 
               then do;
                  Zip = ' ';
                  Address = value;
                  end;
               else do;
                  Address = substr(value,1,length(value) - length(scan(value,-1,' '))-1);;
                  end;
            end;
         when ('Phone') do;
            Phone = value;
            end;
         when ('Fax') do;
            Fax = value;
            end;
         when ('http') do;
            Website = 'http:' || value;
            end;
         otherwise do;
            putlog 'Unknown variable: ' var;
            end;
         end;

      end;
run;
```

This is an old-school solution and I'm sure there is a more modern way using regular expressions.  It uses a loop to step through your Company_Address variable, parsing out columns identified by a colon prefix.  It works fine for the example string provided.

I also added a check for valid ZIP code, but note that this only works for 5-digit ZIP codes and will generate an error message in the log for invalid codes (which you can ignore).

Comment: looks lil longway, but yes it did worked, thanks for the solution bob.